# More convenient way to do arithmetic with program output at the shell?

Tags: linux, shell, math

I usually need to run programs to do some file checking, like say use `wc` to count the lines of a file and then do some arithmetic with it. Usually the way I do this is just getting the output and then doing the arithmetic by opening a python terminal or whichever software can be used to do so.

If I have to do it many times, then this gets a bit annoying, and I'd like to have some method to take the output directly and do the arithmetic that I want. For instance, one that I like is using perl in the following way, assuming I have to take the output of `wc` and divide it by 12:

```
perl -e 'print `wc -l file`/12'
```

This can be useful but gets annoying after a while. Since this is probably something people need to do all the time, I'd like to know what better faster methods people use to do this fast. I've seen `expr` might be even better, but I get a syntax error when passing it the output of something bound in ``` `` ```, like above. So basically the shortest, most efficient way one can do this simple arithmetic in linux terminals from file outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double parentheses `((...))` perform arithmetic, and with a dollar sign `$((...))` you can get the result as a string.

```
echo $((`wc -l < file` / 12))
echo $(($(wc -l < file) / 12))
```

You can use variables and they don't need dollar signs. Both `var` and `$var` are acceptable:

```
lines=$(wc -l < file)
echo $((lines / 12))

if ((lines * 42 + 17 > 630)); then
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically I have tested with a code on my bash:
Multiline code:

```
a=$(echo "hi" | wc -l)
echo $a
b=`expr $a + 2`
echo $b
```

Which I have changed to one line:

```
echo `expr $(echo "hi" | wc -l) + 20`
```

1. `echo "hi" | wc -l` is calculating no of lines and is within `$()` which makes it as one variable and evaluate its value
2. Then `expr` takes two arguements here and make sure you to use space before and after the operator and use a backtic(`) to evaluate thi and doing echo finally